# Protect routes and redirect user based on some conditions with Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The scenario is:

For some routes in my app, I want to force user to complete their profile first.

There are a few ways to achieve that:

1. Redirect inside the user resolve (where we load the user data)
2. Listen to `$stateChangeStart` event, load user from server, check if profile is complete

With method 1, is it possible to reuse the user resolve for other routes (given the fact that user resolve pending on auth resolve)?

With method 2, I feel like this method is bug-prone and hard to keep track.

Is there any best practice to this problem?

Comment: for the first point you can use resolve in a service and reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `service` in the `resolve` to reduce the code in the `routes` and `reuse` the `resolve function`

Here is an example implementation of it.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('inbox', {
    ...
    resolve: {
      profile: function (UserService) {
        return UserService.getUser();
      },
    }
  })
  .state('dashboard', {
    ...
    resolve: {
      profile: function (UserService) {
        return UserService.getUser();
      },
    }
  });
```

**Your controller can be,**

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('DashboardCtrl', DashboardCtrl);

function DashboardCtrl(profile,$scope) {
  this.user_profile = profile;
}
```

[HEre is the reference](https://toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/)

**Update:**

You can use the `redirection` in the `resolve` like,

```
resolve: {
  profile: function (UserService,$state) {
    return UserService.getUser().then(function(profile){
    if (profile.id) {
        return profile;
  } else {
        $state.go('/')
  }
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where will the redirection code be?

Comment: you can get the `response` from the `service`, use the `then promise` and redirect here itself.

Comment: Thank you, how should I reuse this resolve across routes?